# Articles: “a” or “the” with “second assumption”?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I wonder if I have to use ***a***, or ***the*** when I introduce two assumptions in an academic paper.

For example, in an introduction section of an article
it tells us that there are two assumptions that the authors will discuss in the section 3 and 4 respectively.

> Section 3 investigates sensitivity to one of the methodology's
>   major assumptions:
>   Dirichlet distribution of the shape frailty.
>
> Section  4 investigates **a** (OR) **the** second major assumption:
>   that size and shape frailty variables are statistically independent.

- Should they use **a** or **the** for “second assumption”?

Answer (score 2):

The [indefinite article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and) is used when we don't know exactly which one is being referred to.

So if more than one possibility exists for that *second major assumption*, use the indefinite article. If exactly one possibility exists for that *second major assumption*, use the definite article.